# Centering a div?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, whatever I try, I can't get this div to center. I've been researching probably for about an hour and can't seem to find something that will get it to center.

Here's what it looks like right now:
http://niil.me/

and here's the CSS:

```
.primary-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 294px;
  min-height: 110px;
  background: #transparent;
  z-index: 300000;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

EDIT: Guess I didn't research hard enough. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this to your css:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 1):

add `transform: translateX(-50%);` then it will be in center

Comment: you just need to add transform: translate(-50%);  not both after one another

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider the width while setting the left. Set the left to

`left: calc(50% - 148px);`

Answer (score 0):

```
   body{

padding-top: 12%;
}

.primary-container {

  width: 294px;
  min-height: 110px;
  background: #transparent;
  z-index: 300000;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below css code:

```
.primary-container {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 300000;
}
```

Comment: @nil can you try above code it work

Comment: This one works, although it leaves a few pixels on the right side of the screen open where I can scroll, but Johans fix worked for me.